# SOCP or SDP optimization problem

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, semidefinite-programming, non-convex-optimization, second-order-cone-programming

I am studying an optimization problem

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{w}^* = \text{argmax} \sum_{d=1}^D \log \bigg( \frac{|\mathbf{f}_d^H\mathbf{w}|^2+c_1}{|\mathbf{f}_d^H\mathbf{w}|^2+c_2} \bigg)\\
\\ 
\text{subject to} \quad |\mathbf{h}_k^H\mathbf{w}|^2\;\ge c_3,\qquad k=1,\ldots,K\\
|\mathbf{w}_k^H\mathbf{w}|^2 \;=\;1
\end{equation}

where all the bold-faced letters are N×1 vectors and the c's are scalar constants.

I tried to use several approximations and manipulations to put the problem in the form of a SOCP or a SDP (since I think those are the most probable programs that the problem would simplify to) but I could not. I would appreciate any help or hint on how to get a solution.

Comment: This problem is not convex, so there is no way it can be converted to SDP or SOCP form, or any other convex form for that matter, without approximation.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I know it is not convex and I want to approximate it to a convex one, I just do not know what approximations to do to convert it.

Comment: I am afraid there is just no standard set of approaches in a situation like this. This is "highly" non-convex: the nonlinear equation, the logarithms in the objective, the ratios within those logarithms, the *lower* bounds on $|h_k^Hw|$... I just don't see it happening. (Then again, if you succeed in finding a useful approximation, you'll have yourself a nice journal article.)